# The needle in highcharts speedometer gauge is very slow to react to changes in the speed value in an animation is there a way to make it more dynamic?

Tags: highcharts

The needle in the highcharts  speedometer gauge is very slow to react to speed changes in an animation. I wonder if there is a parameter that can adjust how fast reacts to new speed value

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `animation.duration` property:

```
    chart: {
        ...,
        animation: {
            duration: 500
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3y0etwph/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.animation